# How to get the created file bytes from CreateDocument in Android Document Provider c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-fileprovider

I am trying to get to grips with creating a custom document provider on Android Xamarin.

I have got an example base template from here...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/storageprovider/

This creates a dummy provider using the internal memory of the phone, I would instead like to swap this out to use a cloud provider and then read/write the data to cloud storage.

I have managed to get it reading ok, but when I try and save I cannot work out how to get the data to then save to the cloud.

When you press save on the phone it hits the following method in the example provider code.

```
    public override string CreateDocument (string parentDocumentId, string mimeType, string displayName)
    {
        Log.Verbose(TAG, "createDocument");

        File parent = GetFileForDocId (parentDocumentId);
        var file = new File (parent, displayName);
        try {
            file.CreateNewFile ();
            file.SetWritable (true);
            file.SetReadable (true);
        } catch (IOException) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException ("Failed to create document with name " +
                displayName +" and documentId " + parentDocumentId);
        }
        return GetDocIdForFile (file);
    }
```

If I then step past this, it goes off to external code and then returns into this method, I am assuming the file create perhaps goes on in between these steps?

```
public override ICursor QueryDocument(string documentId, string[] projection)
{
    Log.Verbose(TAG, "queryDocument");

    // Create a cursor with the requested projection, or the default projection.
    var result = new MatrixCursor(ResolveDocumentProjection(projection));
    IncludeFile(result, documentId, null);
    return result;
}
```

I would like to be able to get the byte array of the file being saved, so I can then call the API to upload to the cloud server.

Is this possible and does anyone have any pointers/examples on how to do this?  I have tried getting the bytes like this..

```
var bytes = fullyReadFileToBytes(file);
```

using the following method, but this always returns 0 bytes.  I am assuming that the file creation in this method is just creating the placeholder for the file but not actually creating it here.  Is there another method I can override which is called after CreateDocument perhaps where I can get this byte array from?

```
public byte[] fullyReadFileToBytes(File f)
{
    int size = (int)f.Length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    byte[] tmpBuff = new byte[size];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f); ;
    try
    {

        int read = fis.Read(bytes, 0, size);
        if (read < size)
        {
            int remain = size - read;
            while (remain > 0)
            {
                read = fis.Read(tmpBuff, 0, remain);
                System.Array.Copy(tmpBuff, 0, bytes, size - remain, read);
                remain -= read;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        fis.Close();
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you writing to that file before you try to read it? I see no code. And you did not tell.

Comment: I am not sure where it is written is maybe the issue, the Android app takes me straight to that CreateDocument method and then returns.  Then returns into the QueryDocument method from external code (assuming to populate into current folder listing), so guessing somewhere in the middle it is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer the file is only properly written after it closes it's handle.

So if you try and read the bytes in the OnClose method, this brings back the file data needed.

```
class MyOnCloseListener : Java.Lang.Object, ParcelFileDescriptor.IOnCloseListener
{
    string documentID;

    public MyOnCloseListener(string documentId)
    {
        documentID = documentId;
    }

    public void OnClose(Java.IO.IOException e)
    {
        // Update the file with the cloud server.  The client is done writing.
        var file = GetFileForDocId(documentID);
        var bytes = fullyReadFileToBytes(file);

        // do stuff here to save to cloud provider
    }
}
```